# Ingressos grátis para conferências

Tags: debate, comunidade

Tenho ingressos com desconto (até 100%) para o [MVPConf](https://mvpconf.com.br/) que acontecerá em São Paulo dias 12 e 13 e para o [TDC Florianópolis](http://www.thedevelopersconference.com.br/tdc/2019/florianopolis/trilhas) de 23 à 27 deste mês.

Quem pegar tem que ir, nem que esteja morrendo :) principalmente quem pegar 100%. Pede e ganhe de acordo com sua participação no site (sim, só estou dando para usuários do SOpt porque vocês são demais e me ajudam muito). Pode pedir aqui, nas minhas redes sociais ou outra forma que conseguir falar comigo. Pode ser mais fácil do que imagina.

Só um pequeno detalhe, farei duas palestras em 3 sessões, mas todas estão esgotadas.

Agora só tem para o TDC.

Comment: "porque vocês são demais" <3

Comment: @Maniero Vou ver ela no dia 13...

Comment: @RenanCarlos só farei no dia 12 :P mas estarei lá dia 13 porque ajudo na organização.

Comment: @Maniero Acabei de confirmar aqui, tem uma palestra sua pro dia 13/04 as 16:00 no `PowerApps` tá cancelada?

Comment: @RenanCarlos é mesmo, mudaram então :)